# Did Richard Nixon commission a study on the effects of THC and then have the results classified?

Tags: medical-science, politics, alternative-medicine, marijuana

This was recently shared to my mother's Facebook page.  She is currently battling an aggressive cancer that was brought on by Chemotherapy that she had to fight stage 4 breast cancer over 10 years ago.

> The US Government has known since 1974 that Cannabis cures Cancer. In
>   '72 Richard Nixon wanted a larger budget for his war on drugs. He
>   thought that if he proved Cannabis caused lung cancer like cigarettes
>   do, he would get the support he needed. He gave the Medical College of
>   Virginia 2 years to do a study on the effects of THC on the body. In
>   '74 the study was completed. It turns out, THC when ingested in highly
>   concentrated forms (such as eating Cannabis oil) will attack any
>   mutated cells in your body while strengthening and rejuvenating the
>   healthy cells. They found the PERFECT cure for Cancer. It worked fast,
>   it worked well, it worked on many different forms of Cancer in ALL
>   stages and it had ZERO harmful side effects. (Unlike Chemo which
>   deteriorates your entire body and kills 1 in 5 patients. Not only
>   that, but it dissolves ALL forms of tumors and can even combat
>   super-bugs like MRSA.) When Richard Nixon saw the results of the study
>   he was FURIOUS. He threw the entire report in the trash and deemed the
>   study classified. In 1976 President Gerald Ford put an end to all
>   public cannabis research and granted exclusive research rights to
>   major pharmaceutical companies, who set out — unsuccessfully — to
>   develop synthetic forms of THC that would deliver all the medical
>   benefits without the “high.”
>
> We only found out about the study a few years ago thanks to dedicated
>   medical and law professionals who filed Freedom of Information
>   Requests. The Govt lied for many reasons.. One of the main reasons is
>   Pharmaceutical Companies. They spend billions every year lobbying to
>   keep Cannabis illegal because they make TRILLIONS off Cancer drugs and
>   research. They are already well aware that Cannabis cures Cancer. They
>   have a great con going at the moment. Cancer patients and their loved
>   ones will spend their entire life savings or even sell their houses
>   and businesses in order to pay for Chemotherapy and other Cancer
>   treatment drugs. A lot of the time they spend all that money and their
>   loved one dies anyway. If the public found out that the Government has
>   been lying for over 40 years, that MILLIONS of lives could have been
>   saved and that the dying could grow the cure they need in their
>   backyard... The Public would be going APE-SHIT.
>
> PLEASE keep an open mind about this. I realize it's hard to believe
>   but I PROMISE YOU, it's true. If you want to know more, you should
>   Google 'Cannabis Cures Cancer'. You will see that there are thousands
>   of published scientific studies, articles, books and documentaries on
>   the subject. Id start with the film 'Run From The Cure'. Its one of my
>   favorites
>
> (Comment from the admin): I feel the need to be EXCEPTIONALLY CLEAR
>   here because many people have attacked me for sharing this
>   information. SMOKING CANNABIS DOES NOT CURE CANCER. EATING CANNABIS
>   OIL DOES. There have been A LOT of skeptics about this. I highly
>   suggest you actually RESEARCH THIS SUBJECT rather than demonize the
>   people that have already actually researched it. Cannabis DOES CURE
>   CANCER... This is not a rumor, this is not some internet hoax.. THIS
>   IS A FACT. Every single person I know that's tried this cure, has
>   successfully cured their cancer. Do you get what I'm saying? I KNOW
>   PEOPLE WHO WOULD NOT BE HERE TODAY IF IT WEREN'T FOR THIS CURE. Plenty
>   of people have posted proof online. Check before you doubt!!
>
> Start here :
>
> Cannabis Cures Cancer and the Government Knows it:
>   http://themindunleashed.org/2013/07/cannabis-cures-cancer-and-government.html
>
> 34 Medical Studies Proving Cannabis Cures Cancer:
>   http://themindunleashed.org/2013/12/34-medical-studies-proving-cannabis-cures-cancer.html
>
> A Molecular Biologist Explains How THC Completely Kills Cancer:
>   http://themindunleashed.org/2014/04/molecular-biologist-explains-thc-completely-kills-cancer.html
>
> Recipe To Make Cannabis Oil For Chemo Alternative:
>   http://themindunleashed.org/2014/05/recipe-make-cannabis-oil-chemo-alternative.html

*To be clear I am **not** trying to challenge the claims about marijuana's effects on cancer ([that has been done here](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/10229/3126)).*

My question is did Nixon commission such  a study from the Medical College of Virginia in 1972?
If so were the results Classified in 1974 but recently made available through FOIA?
And finally, if so, is there any reasonable interpretation of the results that would correlate with the claims here?

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:alternative-medicine]?

Comment: @rob: if eating cannabis oil to treat cancer isn't "alternative medicine", I don't know what is.

Comment: @NateEldredge Well, there is evidence that it works as referenced in the other questions answer and on [cancer.gov](http://www.cancer.gov/cancertopics/pdq/cam/cannabis/healthprofessional/page4) so I wouldn't exactly call this alternative medicine to begin with. However, that is tangential to the fact that the question isn't about efficacy but if a study was actually classified. I think that [tag:united-states], [tag:history], and [tag:marijuana] are a better fit with the question of efficacy left to the other question.

Comment: @Rob It could have been commissioned then classified but not have the conclusion/results as claimed as well.

Comment: @Chad True, but this question doesn't appear to be about the efficacy of THC (if so it's a duplicate) but about the history of a given study/report. Plus, if THC is an effective treatment (still being studied) then it's not an alternative medicine, it's medicine. ;)

Comment: If you feel that strongly about it ask the question on Meta not here.  Even if you disagree with the tagging I am sure you can see how a reasonable person would tag it this way.  So that means the discussion does not belong in comments.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This claim ultimately traces back to a May 30, 2000, article published by AlterNet, [Pot Shrinks Tumors; Government Knew in '74](http://www.alternet.org/story/9257/pot_shrinks_tumors%3B_government_knew_in_%2774), and [a book first published in 1985](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Emperor_Wears_No_Clothes).

The AlterNet story claims that:

> In 1974 researchers at the Medical College of Virginia, who had been funded by the National Institute of Health to find evidence that marijuana damages the immune system, found instead that THC slowed the growth of three kinds of cancer in mice -- lung and breast cancer, and a virus-induced leukemia.
>
> The DEA quickly shut down the Virginia study and all further cannabis/tumor research, according to Jack Herer, who reports on the events in his book, "[The Emperor Wears No Clothes](http://www.jackherer.com/thebook/)." In 1976 President Gerald Ford put an end to all public cannabis research and granted exclusive research rights to major pharmaceutical companies . . .

That book offers [somewhat more detail](http://www.jackherer.com/thebook/chapter-seven/):

> A tumor is a mass of swollen tissue. Researchers at the Medical College of Virginia discovered that cannabis is an incredibly successful herb for reducing many types of tumors, both benign and malignant (cancerous).
>
> The DEA and other federal agencies had ordered these tumor studies done after hearing erroneous reports of possible immunicological problems associated with cannabis smoke. But, in 1975, instead of health problems, an apparent medical breakthrough occurred and successful tumor reductions were recorded!
>
> Following this remarkably positive discovery by the Medical College of Virginia, orders were immediately handed down by the DEA and the National Institutes of Health to defund all further cannabis/tumor research and reporting! Millions of Americans who might be alive today are dead because of these and other DEA orders regarding marijuana.
>
> In 1996 and 2006, the Medical College of Virginia again applied to receive grants for cannabis research and again were turned down by the DEA.

The referenced paper, [Antineoplastic activity of cannabinoids](http://jnci.oxfordjournals.org/content/55/3/597), was actually published in the Journal of the National Cancer Institute in 1975. Copies of it found on the Internet state that it was:

> Supported by Public Health Service grant DA00490 from the National Institute on Drug Abuse, Health Services & Mental Health Administration; by a grant from the Alexander and Margaret Stewart Trust Fund; and by an institutional grant from the American Cancer Society.

All information I could find as to whether the DEA defunded cannabis research in 1975 ultimately refer back to one of these two sources. As far as I can tell, though, the paper itself was never suppressed *per se*; it was indeed published and was (and still is) available in the academic literature.

Comment: Even after publishing the article you cite, the same group published Effects of δ9-Tetrahydrocannabinol in Lewis Lung Adenocarcinoma Cells in Tissue Culture JNCI J Natl Cancer Inst (1976) 56 (3): 655-658  http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/943561